# Spark Remote execution to Cluster fails - HDFS connection Refused at 8020

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am having issues submitting a spark-submit remote job from a machine outside from the Spark Cluster running on YARN.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectionException: Call from remote.dev.local/192.168.10.65 to target.dev.local:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectionException: Connection Refused
```

In my core-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://target.dev.local:8020</value>
<property>
```

Also at my hdfs-site.xml in the cluster I have disbled permissions checking for HDFS:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
  <value>false</value>
<property>
```

Also, when I telnet from the machine outside the cluster:

```
telnet target.dev.local 8020
```

I am getting

```
telnet: connect to address 192.168.10.186: Connection Refused
```

But, when I

```
telnet target.dev.local 9000
```

it says **Connected**.

Also when I `ping target.dev.local` it works.

My spark-submit script from the remote machine is:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/<path_to_conf_dir_copied_from_cluster>/

spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--driver-memory 5g \
--executor-memory 50g \
--executor-cores 5 \
--queue default \
<path to jar>.jar \
10
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to change

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://target.dev.local:8020</value>
<property>
```

to

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value>
<property>
```

to allow connections form the outside since target.dev.local sits in a private network switch.